# TypeScript does not enforce type check for function arguments

Tags: javascript, typescript

I had an impression that TypeScript allowed you to take a valid JavaScript program and "enforce" types by making a few key symbols type-safe. This would propagate the types through all the usages, and make you update all the symbol references.

This seems to be incorrect. In the following example the `makeDiv` function is calling a typed `make` function without checking the parameter type.

```
// strongly typed arguments
function make(tagName: string, className: string) {
    alert ("Make: " + className.length);
}

// no typing
function makeDiv(className) {
    // calling the typed function without type checking
    return make("div", className);
}

makeDiv("test"); 
makeDiv(6); // bang!
```

Do I miss something here? Is there is a way to enforce "stricter" type checking? Or is this a design decision made by TypeScript creators?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a design decision. Anything not explicitly typed becomes implicitly typed to be of type `any`. `any` is compatible with *all* types.

```
var x:any = 123;
x = "bang";
```

To prevent *implicit* typing of a variable to be `any` there is a compiler flag (`--noImplicitAny`) starting with TypeScript 0.9.1

If you compile with this option your code will **not compile** *unless* you do:

```
// You need to explicitly mention when you want something to be of any type. 
function makeDiv(className:any) {
    // calling the typed function without type checking
    return make("div", className);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @basarat. What I didn't understand was that `any` is compatible with all types (as you pointed out) in two ways. I mentally associated it with C# object, which could be downcasted from string, but not the other way around.

Comment: Actually, anything not explicitly typed has a type inferred if possible. E.g. `var x = 3` becomes a number, and `function a() { alert('abc') }` returns `void`.   For some reason you are allowed to return the `void` value that `a()` returns from another function, i.e. `function b() { return a() }` but `b()` is implied to return `void`